# Why my Three.js code isn't working when i test it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, three.js

I'm trying out Three.js, I followed a tutorial step-by-step. In the code editor I'm using( Visual Studio Code 2019) everything seems normal, but when I test it, nothing appears on the page.

the editor I'm using, used the desktop as the place to locate my code, since it is a .html file I could run it. When I did that, the only thing that appeared was the navbar I programmed, nothing else

```
This is the entire three.js code:
<script src="three.js-dev/build/three.min.js"> </script>
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight);

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias = true});
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            $('body').append( renderer.domElement);

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial ( { color = 0xff0000 });
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material) ;
            scene.add( cube );

            cube.position.z = -5;
            var animate = function () {

             cube.rotation.x += 0.01;

                renderer.render(scene, camera);
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            };
            animate();
```

and this the code before it:

```
<html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script 
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"
        integrity="sha256-siFczlgw4jULnUICcdm9gjQPZkw/YPDqhQ9+nAOScE4="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="navbar"><span>Three.js Tut</span></div>
```

I expected a red cube rotating, but nothing appeared. ¿Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-debugging-javascript.html and https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-setup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few errors in your code:

- `THREE.scene` should be `THREE.Scene`
- `{antialias = true}` should be `{antialias: true}`
- `{ color = 0xff0000 }` should be `{ color: 0xff0000 }`

Live demo with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/so736vxj/

BTW: If you are using VSCode, I'm a bit irritated that no errors are highlighted. Especially the last two syntax errors should be reported since it is no valid JavaScript.

`three.js R105`